# C# Unused fields in base classes

Tags: c#, field, base-class

In a prism application I have a module definition like this:

```
[Module(ModuleName = "TestModule", OnDemand = true)]
public class Test :
    ModelBase,
    IModule
{
  ...
  moduleName = "TestModule";
  ...
};
```

As you can see, these modules will be loaded at runtime and there are many of them with different module names.

In order to avoid code redundancy, I've written a base class *ModelBase* from which these models derive as follows:

```
public class ModelBase:
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The module name
    /// </summary>        
    protected string moduleName;
    ...
}
```

The string moduleName is never used in ModelBase, so I get the compiler warning CS0169 which says excactly this.
I don't like to suppress warnings, so I'm wondering if there is a better solution.

moduleName will be set with the actual name in the derived class as you can see in the 1st snippet.

The problem is that one cannot assign a name in the ModelBase class, since the module's name is not known here in advance.

This problem might sound stupid since one could write

```
public class ModelBase:
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The module name
    /// </summary>        
    protected string moduleName = "";
    ...
}
```

to overcome this issue.

I wonder if there is a "best practise" for this recurring question.
Many thanks

Juergen

Comment: Non-private, non-constant fields are a code-smell, IMO. Why not use a (perhaps abstract) property here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would personally make this an abstract property:

```
protected abstract string ModuleName { get; }
```

As an extra bonus, this will force the derived class to implement it, which should reduce the potential for errors.  If your usage of the `ModuleName` should be public, you can of course make the property public, as well.

A similar alternative would be to make this a constructor parameter of your class:

```
protected ModelBase(string name)
{
    this.moduleName = name;
}
```

This would, again, force this to be handled in each derived class as part of the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that ModuleBase classes can be instatiated, they should have a name assigned if the string exists within them.

If they aren't supposed to be instantiated, consider making ModuleBase an abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can consider initializing the moduleName to `null` in the constructor or as part of the member variable definition, since `System.String` is a reference type.

Answer (score 1):

Make model base an abstract class and then define model name as an absract readonly property like this...

```
Protected abstract string modelname { get; }
```

This will ensure that derived classes give a model name